# For Loop and Map Equivalent Don't Match Up

Tags: r

I'm trying to replicate list assignment within a for-loop with a map function. The set-up is very straightforward. First we create a list object with a pre-determined length:

```
list_one <- vector(mode = "list", length = 5)
```

And then we loop over it with a named vector:

```
for(i in seq_along(list_one)){ 
  list_one[[i]][["percent.mt"]] <- "HELLO"
}
```

I thought the map equivalent would be this:

```
list_two <- vector(mode = "list", length = 5)

list_two <- map(list_two, ~ { 
  .x[["percent.mt"]] <- "HELLO"
  })
```

But here's how the two lists look:

```
> list_one
[[1]]
[[1]]$percent.mt
[1] "HELLO"

[[2]]
[[2]]$percent.mt
[1] "HELLO"

[[3]]
[[3]]$percent.mt
[1] "HELLO"

[[4]]
[[4]]$percent.mt
[1] "HELLO"

[[5]]
[[5]]$percent.mt
[1] "HELLO"

> list_two
[[1]]
[1] "HELLO"

[[2]]
[1] "HELLO"

[[3]]
[1] "HELLO"

[[4]]
[1] "HELLO"

[[5]]
[1] "HELLO"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrong syntax. Replace

```
.x[["percent.mt"]] <- "HELLO"
```

with

```
`[[<-`(.x, "percent.mt", "HELLO")
```

Or

```
.x[["percent.mt"]] <- "HELLO"; .x
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not as good for not using `map` syntax, but this works also:

```
list_two <- map(list_two, function(x){x <- list("percent.mt" = "HELLO")})
```